# How to trace which file causing redirection in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a blog page which is redirected to another page. How to trace which file causing blog page to redirect. All other pages are working fine, except this blog page. How to track it?
Apache version 2.4.7
This is my htaccess code

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /foldername/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /foldername/index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: some parts, which you can to check. go to `edit page` of that page, wich redicrects and edit it. look at it: find some `js` code, if it not exists, look at template. If there is isn't template, look at `functions.php` file of active theme. check plugins, which may have some redirect features. Provide us everything you found.

Comment: htacces is ok. the redirect rules may be some other part of the website. we can't guess where is it. provide more details, such as I wrote above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not htaccess file problem. it redirects blog page to another page then check your WordPress file.

Comment: which file to check i didtn write any condition

Comment: first, check your setting in WordPress or you can be used any page builder to create a page?

Comment: can you give me your site details then I can check and solve the issue?